# Is it possible to get informed about mongodb collection changes?

Tags: c#, mongodb

Is it possible to get informed if something is changed in a collection in mongodb? For example some new document is added to the collection. Is it possible to be subscribed to these changes? Does any implementation for C# exist? Thanks.

Comment: May you please specify what type of `Collections` is it? Have a great day :)

Comment: Thanks for providing the information. I'm currently downloading [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/dr/downloads.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-i386-2.2.1.zip/download) to have a look into this. Have a great day :)

Comment: Sorry I was unable to find a solution for this. Sorry about that :(

Answer (score 4):

As @Sergio says, not inherently, however you can use a tailable cursor to achieve something similar:

http://blog.mongodb.org/post/29495793738/pub-sub-with-mongodb

#### Edit

Realised that article is a bit bare, this might be a better one: http://www.devco.net/archives/2012/08/31/using-mongodb-as-a-queue.php

Comment: +1. It is worth mentioning that Tailable Cursors can only be used on [capped collections](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collections)

Answer (score 2):

No, there are no hooks or triggers in MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any plans of having it? Or maybe some custom or open source implementations?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there are no plans of adding them.